# Exact positioning of page numbers at the top of each page

Tags: page-numbering

Good day everyone. I need some help on my report. My professor requires me to place page number on each page at exactly 1.25 inch from the top on the right side of the paper.  Hope you can help me. Below is my sample code.

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \pagestyle{fancy}


 \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
 \fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % except the center
 }

 \begin{document}

 \chapter{Introduction}
 \lipsum

 \chapter{Review}
 \lipsum

 \end{document}
```

Comment: 1.25 inch is the bottom 'line' of your page number, so that the foot of the number is placed one that 'line' or is the page number top aligned to that `1.25in` top margin? And I suppose that the page number should only the right side if is on a page with odd number, i.e. a *recto* page and on the left side, if it is a *verso* page?

Answer (score 3):

This solution also uses the `geometry` package, but takes into account the depth of descenders in the current font. If you want the baseline of page numbers to be exactly at 1.25in from the top of the papersheet, you add these lines to your preamble:

```
\newlength{\adjustd}
\settodepth{\adjustd}{gjpqy}  
\usepackage[top=\dimexpr 1.25in + \headsep + \adjustd \relax]{geometry}
```

The following snapshot shows why descenders must be taken into account (geometry loaded with option `showframe`):

[image]

If it's the top of page numbers that you want to be at 1.25in, you have to add two more lines:

```
\newlength{\adjusta}
\settoheight\adjusta{0123456789}
```

For uppercase figures, 0 will be enough.

and replace last line above with:

```
\usepackage[top=\dimexpr 1.25in +\headsep + \adjustd + \adjusta \relax]{geometry}
```

Of course, if your page numbers use oldstyle figures, 1.25 will be the distance from highest figures (5 and 8) to the top of the sheet, and figures with descenders (3, 4, 5, 7 and 9) should be taken into account in the definition of `\adjd`. If you want that the top of figures `without` ascenders be at 1.25in, replace  the definition of `\adjusta` with

```
\settoheight\adjusta{01234579}.
```

Comment: I wonder a little bit about the descenders with figures. Is it necessary for 'usual' page number figures to regard descenders (I agree with some kind of calligraphic figures, oldstyle figures, there might be descenders), but perhaps you could provide a screen shot where such descenders occur?

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer: Actually there are two problems, and I don't know which you refer to: 1. In any case, simply choosing `top=1.25in + headsep` will make the baseline of ordinary figures *not* be at 1.25in of the top of the sheet, but a little less, because headheight takes into account descenders, hnce the 1st solution. I'll include a screenshot that shows this.  2. The case of old style figures for page numbering has been taken into account to be as complete as possible. I agree with you: usual academic work does not use them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I noted that 'slight' vertical offset in my version too, now I know why, since you explained it. And regarding the second aspect: I was just curious and did not want to criticize you. I agree with you, that style of figures other than 'usual' page number style will occure rarely in papers or in a thesis.

Answer (score 2):

The `\topmargin` length is what you're likely looking for. See [Page Layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) in the LaTeX Wikibook, or the following for more options:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layout}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.25in}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % except the right

\begin{document}

\layout{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just too close, the page number is about 1.35 inch from the top when I tried to print it on an A4-sized paper. I changed the length of the top margin from 0.25 to 0.15, and I got the correct format. Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest usage of the `geometry` package, with `tmargin=1.25in` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[showframe=true,tmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % except the center
}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\chapter{Review}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines are introduced by the `showframe=true` option, just for checking.

Comment: I used this and printed a page on an A4 paper. However, the page number is just at 0.85 from the top.

Comment: I printed it too and the bottom of the figure was about 1.14in from the top, which is not 1.25in, that is true. The top of the figure was about 1in from the top paper edge.